# Can two laser diodes of the same type and wavelength, be synchronized to emit light in the same phase, while working in a CW mode.?

Tags: experimental-physics, speed-of-light, laser, electronics, light-emitting-diodes

Can two laser diodes of the same type, power and wavelength, be synchronized to emit light with lightwaves in the same phase,  while working in a continuous wave mode (CW) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, is, no, not easily. Even tuning two diode lasers that are notionally identical to within a few gigahertz of each other is not trivial.

The long answer is, it's not actually impossible, but you'd have to use some kind of feedback mechanism to actively control the phase of one of the lasers to match the other, and you'd need to use lasers with fairly long coherence times (for diode lasers), and you'd need some external optics to measure the relative phase of the two lasers and control the feedback loop.

Comment: Can you explain why tuning laser diodes be nontrivial to within gigahertz, if you can buy preselected diodes with wavelength matched to 1/10 of nm and with linewidth of a few kHz, or you can buy tunable laser diodes with linewidth of a few MHz?

Comment: @Jimski, a 0.1 nm difference at 1550 nm is a 12.5 GHz difference in frequency. At shorter wavelengths, the frequency difference would be even larger. Linewidth isn't directly related to wavelength accuracy, so those figures aren't relevant to the question asked.

Comment: As for tunable lasers, you do want a narrow linewidth here so your phase-lock feedback mechanism can keep up with laser phase noise --- so you probably want to use an external cavity for your tuning mechanism --- and I'd consider that "non-trivial" already.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. As far as pahse locking is concerned I was thinking about taking some light from one laser and feeding it through a fiber directly into the cavity of another closely matched laser. Of course this is just a simplification of what would need to be done.

Comment: @Jimski, I'm not sure what you're trying to do but it might make more sense to just use a bigger laser to begin with and split its output into two beams. Or use a master-oscillator power-amplifier (MOPA) setup. Then you get phase matched outputs without a lot of complexity.

Comment: Coupled oscillators may be phase-locked without an explicit loop if the coupled energy is enough to overcome whatever tuning offsets and noise disturbs their individual phases. Early analog TV worked this way: there were no phase-locked loops, just circuitry that detected sync pulses and kicked the oscillators periodically. Perhaps diode lasers could be synced by sufficient cross-coupling.

Comment: @JohnDoty, that's essentially what OP suggests in a comment above...But how do you ensure that the coupling just causes phase locking and not mode hopping, power fluctuations, and other problems? I'm also interpreting the question to be about two devices purchased separately and not about devices integrated on the same chip. (If you wanted two phase-locked beams from devices on the same chip, I suspect a MOPA would give better results)

Comment: My point is that your assertion of a requirement for an external loop is not correct.

Comment: @JohnDoty, it's down to semantics and whether OP is looking for a practical answer or pure theory. Even in pure theory, you could think of whatever couples light between the two cavities as "external optics" (external to either cavity).